# Deducting 24 hours from a timestamp

Tags: php

I am wondering if there is an easy way to do this, i'm pulling a timestamp from mysql, i then want to check if the timestamp is less than 24 hours ago, if it is, i do nothing, else i will do an action, my code:

```
        $dbStoredDate   = $theDate['site_date'];    
        $theTimeMinus   = strtotime('-1 day', $dbStoredDate);   

        if ($theTimeMinus <= $dbStoredDate) {

        }
```

This is what i have come up with, i realize now it would have been better if i used time() instead of timestamp() in mysql, lesson learned, the first value is coming from mysql, the second is just deducting 1 day, does the logic look ok do you think? thanks for any input guys.

Comment: you could do all the logic in the database if you wanted - and a timestamp column is fine for both use cases

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily (assuming you're using unix timestamp, if not you can convert it):

```
$continue = ((time() >= ($theDate['site_date']+86400));
if ($continue)
   echo "older than/equal to 24 hours";
else
   echo "not older than 24 hours";
```